# Difference between Beta Process and Dirichlet process

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics

I'm trying to understand the definition of a Beta process, as given in the paper:
www.ece.duke.edu/~lcarin/Paisley_BP-FA_ICML.pdf

The problem is that from the definition it follows that every Dirichlet process is also a beta process, which seems, ahm, wrong.  Can you help me figure out what I don't understand?

This is the definition from the paper:
"Let $H_0$ be a continuous probability measure and α a positive scalar. Then for all disjoint, inﬁnitesimal partitions, $B_1 ,\ldots, B_K$, the beta
process is generated as follows,
      $H(B_k) \sim Beta(\alpha H_0 (B_k ), \alpha(1 − H_0(B_k )))$

with K → ∞ and $H_0(B_k)$ → 0 for $k = 1,\ldots,K$. This process is denoted $H \sim BP(\alpha H_0 )$."

This is the definition for a Dirichlet Process (DP):

If $X \sim DP(\alpha H_0)$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar and $H_0$ is a probability distribution, then for every finite partition $A_1,\ldots,A_K$ it follows that
$(X(A_1),\ldots,X(A_K)) \sim DIR(\alpha H_0(A_1), \ldots,\alpha H_0(A_K))$.

So let's assume that I have $X\sim DP(\alpha H_0)$.  Given any partition $B_1 ,\ldots, B_K$, and any $k = 1 \ldots K$, I can define a partition $A_1 = B_k, A_2 = \Omega -B_k$ and from the DP definition it follows that

$(X(A_1),X(A_2)) \sim DIR(\alpha H_0(A_1), \alpha H_0(A_2))$
which is equivalent to saying that
$X(B_k) \sim Beta(\alpha H_0(B_k), \alpha(1-H_0(B_k)))$

hence $X\sim BP(\alpha H_0)$.  Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot conclude $X\sim BP(\alpha H_0)$ just by knowing the marginal distribution of each $X(B_k)$, separately.
Your calculation is not wrong as the univariate marginal distribution and conditional distribution of a Dirichlet distribution are [Beta distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#Stick-breaking_construction).

In particular, in a Dirichlet process, samples correspond to the density function $$f(\theta)=\sum \beta_i \delta_{\theta_i}$$
(Here the $\beta_i$ are constructed as $\beta_i=\beta_i'\prod_{j < i}(1-\beta_j')$, and $\beta_j'\sim \text{Beta}(1,\alpha)=Y$)

While in a Beta process, given an **infinitesimal** partition $(B_1,...,B_K)$ with $K\to \infty$ and $H(B_k)\to 0$ the samples correspond to the density function
$$H(B)=\sum \pi_i\delta_{B_i}$$ where $\pi_i\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha H_0(B_i),\alpha (1-H_0(B_i)))$

I hope you can see the difference. One more thing, the reason why the Dirichlet process is defined in terms of finitely dimensional distributions is because [Kolmogorov extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) guarantees that it defines a stochastic process. Unfortunately the Beta process, does not verify the conditions of this theorem, and as a continuous time Levy process must be defined directly in the infinitesimal limit.

Comment: OK, I think that (thanks to your help) I understand the difference.  Let me put it in my own words:

The definition of the DP was basically a criterion:  "When can we say that X is drawn from a DP?  If at the level of every finite partition X is Dirichlet distributed".

The definition of the BP is an (asymptotic) construction, not a criterion.  It implies, for example, that the atomic weights, $\pi_i$ are drawn independently, unlike the DP (in which they must sum to 1).  

Comment: By the way, regarding your remark on the Kolmogorov extension theorem, you can check this paper: http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_0901.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you say that I can't conclude $X\sim BP(\alpha H_0)$.  I showed above that if $X\sim DP(\alpha H_0)$ then for every partition $B_1...B_K$, $X(B_k)\sim Beta(\alpha H_0(B_k), \alpha(1-H_0(B_k)))$.  By the definition of a Beta Process it follows that $X\sim BP(\alpha H_0)$.  No?

Comment: Jonathan: Oh, I see, you probably couldn't comment because you aren't recognized as the same user.

Comment: Gjergji:  I can't follow your reasoning. 
First, I don't see why $X(B_1)$ will depend on the partition that $B_1$ comes from.  In both definitions (for DP and for BP) $X(B_1)$ only depends on $\alpha$ and $H_0(B_1)$.

Specifically, regarding the partition you suggested $(B_1, B_2, \Omega-(B_1,B_2))$, I will argue that $X(B_1)$ is still Beta distributed.

Comment: I edited my post, hope it makes things clearer.